# Elasticsearch query - Most recent log for each user, for field logtype='x'

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to query elasticsearch to get the most recent log for all userIDs where we only include one log per user with field logtype='x'

if logtype='x' then get 1 log per userID where the date of this log is the most recent for each userID

Example log:{"logtype"="x", "number":232423, "userID":123, "time":"2021-02-03T20:25:44.603045+05:30"}

How can I create this query?

Comment: Please include a sample log entry -- in the format you've used to insert it to ES.

Comment: I added an example log. Is this what you need?

Comment: take a look at collapse: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html

top_hits (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) could also help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your index mapping looks like:

```
{
  "properties" : {
    "logtype" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "number" : {
      "type" : "long"
    },
    "time" : {
      "type" : "date"
    },
    "userID" : {
      "type" : "long"
    }
  }
}
```

you'll need these aggregations: a [`terms`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) ordered by the result of a [`max`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html), plus a [`top_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) to fetch the most recent log per a userId:

```
POST logs/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "logtype": "x"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_user_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userID",
        "size": 1,
        "order": {
          "latest_date": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest_date": {
          "max": {
            "field": "time"
          }
        },
        "latest_log": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                "time": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is close to what I am trying to do, but I when I run this I get logs that have the same userID, and I am trying to get one log per user. Do you know why this is?

Comment: You're welcome. But isn't that the point -- if you want one log per user ID, you'll need to group them by the ID first. Or?

Comment: How should I modify this query to group by the userID first? I thought you were already doing that with this part.
"aggs": {
    "by_user_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userID",

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. It *is* already doing that.